# Purely in performance terms, how do CONTAINS([MyCol], 'foo') and [MyCol] LIKE '%foo%' compare?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2019, full-text-search, like

Consider `CONTAINS([MyCol], 'foo')` and `[MyCol] LIKE '%foo%'`. Assume the best possible indexes on `[MyCol]`, whatever those may be (at minimum, we need a unique key and a full-text index). I know that the two expressions are not equivalent, but how do their performance characteristics compare?

Assume SQL Server 2019. I am asking because I have inherited a codebase where the first expression was frequently preferred over the second, without any documentation explaining why.

Comment: Depends on the choice of items, the contains won't even run and will throw an error. These items aren't equivalent, comparing them makes no sense. You use the one that is needed. If you need fulltext and contains/freetext then use it, otherwise don't. The '%foo%' isn't going to run very well as it'll need to scan all entries.

Comment: @SeanGallardy Feel free to submit that as an answer. You're probably on to something.